# How To Create Animation of Segue perform and unwind segue?

Tags: swift, animation, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

i am working on application where i am trying to call controllers with animations
second view controller with animations
like when i call second controller with segue
second controller come from right and first controller start moving to left 
like android push pop animations

i make some code

```
class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform() {
    let src = self.source
    let dst = self.destination

    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width*2, y: 0)
    //Double the X-Axis
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    }) { (finished) in
        src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }



}
```

}

but from this code new controller come from right i need to move current controller to move left too 
if anyone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let firstVCView: UIView = self.source.view
        let secondVCView: UIView = self.destination.view
        self.destination.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        secondVCView.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            firstVCView.frame = firstVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0.0)
            secondVCView.frame = secondVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0.0)
               }) { (Finished) -> Void in
                self.source.present(self.destination as UIViewController,
                       animated: false,
                       completion: nil)
           }
    }
}


class CustomSegueUnwind: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let secondVCView: UIView = self.source.view
        let firstVCView: UIView = self.destination.view
        self.destination.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(firstVCView, aboveSubview: secondVCView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            firstVCView.frame = firstVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: screenWidth, dy: 0.0)
            secondVCView.frame = secondVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: screenWidth, dy: 0.0)
               }) { (Finished) -> Void in
                self.source.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
           }
    }
}
```

Reference [HERE](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/) for more details

Comment: thanks it will work on unwind also? because its working perfectly when i perform segues

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas I added unwind class. Hope this help

Comment: can you please guide me full way i am beginner in ios i added unwind function its closing the controller but when i press back button controller go down but on segue perform its working good with your code

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas watch [this video for unwind segue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULd2v4mHyQ4). If my answer help your problem, plz vote or check it's correct (or both). Thanks bro!

Comment: thanks brother this is exactly the same i want in ios you are great :D